# Binding an empty list to a ListView control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an empty list object (`lstPersons`) that I'm binding to a ListView control (`lvPersons`). Since `lstPersons` is empty, it seems to never generate the ul in html. Is there a way to still force the html ul list to render even though `lstPersons` is empty? Basically rendering an empty ul, and preferably without having to change the LayoutTemplate?

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvPersons" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">                            
    <LayoutTemplate>                        
        <ul id="ulPersons" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static">
            <li id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></li>
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>            
    <ItemTemplate>                                                                                    
        <li>                
            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%>'></asp:Label>                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        </li>                         
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:ListView>    


List<Person> lstPersons = new List<Person>();
lvPersons.DataSource = lstPersons;
lvPersons.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

The list exists, but there are no items in it. So if you want something to show up you need to add an empty `Person` to the list before binding it to the ListView.

```
List<Person> lstPersons = new List<Person>();

lstPersons.Add(new Person());

lvPersons.DataSource = lstPersons;
lvPersons.DataBind();
```

Comment: Actually after a bit more google searches I think using an EmptyDataTemplate for the ListView control might do the trick. I can put an empty ul in that template.